# check if uint64_t is defined

Tags: c++, types, preprocessor-directive

The type `uint64_t` is not guaranteed to be defined on 32-bit platforms, and code like

```
int main() {
  uint64_t i = 0;
}
```

may result in compilation errors of the type `incomplete type`.

Is there a preprocessor directive to check if `uint64_t` is present? Any other way for checking if the type is defined?

Comment: Consider adding C or C++ tag apropriately to get more attention.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that reasonable approach is to check if associated macro `UINT64_MAX` is defined, e.g.

```
#include <cstdint> /* don't forget to include */

...

#ifdef UINT64_MAX
    ...
#endif
```

AFAIK you can't check directly if some type synonym is defined. According to C99, 7.18.2 Limits of specified-width integer types (don't have copy of C++ standard to confirm, emphasis mine):

> The following object-like macros specify the minimum and maximum
>   limits of the types **declared** in `<stdint.h>`. Each macro name
>   corresponds to a similar type name in 7.18.1.