# Defining a functions for all integers available on a platform

Tags: c++

I would like to write a family of functions for different integers types INT whose signature is

```
INT safe_product(INT a, INT b, bool& error);
```

which takes two integers a and b and returns a * b if a * b does not overflow and returns 0 and sets error to true if a * b does overflow. I also want this function to be efficient and I want it to run on 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

I am thinking of overloading safe_product using `std::int32_t`, `std::uint32_t`, `std::int64_t`, `std::uint64_t`, etc. I believe that `std::int64_t` is not always defined with a 32-bit compiler. Is there a way to know at compile time if it is defined?

Moreover, if we are on a 64-bit plateform, the best way to implement a safe product in between 2 32-bit integers is the following:

```
std::int32_t safe_product(std::int32_t a, std::int32_t b,
                          bool& error) {
  const std::int64_t a_64 = a;
  const std::int64_t b_64 = b;
  const std::int64_t ab_64 = a_64 * b_64;
  if (ab_64 > std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max() ||
      ab_64 < std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min()) {
    error = true;
    return 0;
  } else {
    error = false;
    return static_cast<std::int32_t>(ab_64);
  }
}
```

but if we are a 32-bit platform, the fastest algorithm might imply computing some integer division.

So I have 2 questions:

- How do I declare my `safe_product` so it is defined for all integers types available on my platform (and obviously not for the ones that don't exist)?
- How do I make it efficient on both 32-bit and 64-bit using the algorithms I know?

Comment: `const std::int64_t ab_64 = a * b;` should be `const std::int64_t ab_64 = a_64 * b_64;`, otherwise you are doing a `int32_t` multiplication and the `if` afterwards would be pointless.

Comment: @mch Thanks for spotting the bug

Comment: Consider writing the platform-specific code for a couple most popular platforms. In assembly language, we can just do a multiplication and check the overflow flag after that. That would be much faster than anything you can do in higher level language.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 I'll do that afterwards. There are some intrinsics for gcc and clang that just do that. But I want to be cross-compiler and cross-platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/multiplication-of-large-numbers-how-to-catch-overflow

Comment: @Codor It is different because, here I am not even sure std::int64_t exists. The problem is not the implementation of the function, but how declare it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712091/check-if-uint64-t-is-defined will tell you if you have 64-bit integers or not.

Answer (score 2):

Deducing the fastest integer type in a totally portable way is not a simple task. You might consider using `int_fastXX_t` family of types, but they are not guaranteed to be what you want. You can also look at the size of `void*` and introduce your own logic for deducing the integer type you want to use. For simplicity, I've defined `int` and `unsigned int` to be the fastest integers.

First, define our "fastest" integer types and a helper trait to know if a type is small enough to promote. Anything smaller will be promoted to the "fastest" integer type as you did your in example. Anything equal in size or larger will use integer division to predict overflow.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

// Define the fastest types for our case
using t_fast_int = int;
using t_fast_uint = unsigned int;

// Helper trait, to indicate if a type is small enough to promote
template<class T>
struct t_is_small : std::bool_constant<sizeof(T) < sizeof(t_fast_int)> {};
```

Second, define a generic function and use `enable_if` ([link(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)) to only enable it for small types. This uses the method you describe in your question.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<t_is_small<T>::value, T>
safe_product(T a, T b, bool& error)
{
    // Should we use intmax_t or uintmax_t in this case?
    using t_large = std::conditional_t<std::is_signed<T>::value, t_fast_int, t_fast_uint>;

    const t_large a_64 = a;
    const t_large b_64 = b;
    const t_large ab_64 = a_64 * b_64;
    if (ab_64 > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() ||
        ab_64 < std::numeric_limits<T>::min())
    {
        error = true;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        error = false;
        return static_cast<T>(ab_64);
    }
}
```

Finally, add another overload for large integer types. Notice that the `enable_if` condition is inverted. I've used integer division to anticipate an overflow or underflow.

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<t_is_small<T>::value == false, T>
safe_product(T a, T b, bool& error)
{
    if(b == 0) {
        // The result will be zero (avoids division by zero below)
        error = false;
    }
    else {
        // Calculate the largest `a` that would not result in an overflow
        constexpr auto max_int = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
        auto max_a = max_int / b;

        // Calculate the smallest `a` that would not result in underflow
        constexpr auto min_int = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
        auto min_a = min_int / b;

        // If a is greater than max_a an overflow would occur
        // If a is less than min_a an undeflow would occur
        if(b > 0) {
            error = (a > max_a) || (a < min_a);
        }
        else {
            error = (a < max_a) || (a > min_a);
        }
    }
    if(error) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to think about it, but it looks like a good solution. I'll confirm it as a proper answer once I am familiar with enable_if.

Comment: @InsideLoop The most common solution (that I've seen anyway) to automatically adapt your code to target architecture is to provide a precompiler definition in your project file (VS project file, Makefile, whatever you use) based on the target. Then you can `#if #elif` through the known target architectures in a header.